# NumberFormatter for currency with symbol only in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, numbers, nsnumberformatter

I understand `NumberFormatter`'s default behaviour is to include the country code as part of the symbol if you are not in that country, for example, this test passes:

```swift
func testUSDFromInsideUS() {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.currencyCode = "USD"
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

    XCTAssertEqual("$100.00", formatter.string(from: NSNumber(100)))
}
```

However, when the locale is changed to a country that isn't the US, for example `GB` the number formatter prepends `US` to the `$` sign:

```swift
func testUSDFromOutsideUS() {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.currencyCode = "USD"
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")

    XCTAssertEqual("$100.00", formatter.string(from: NSNumber(100))) // <-- fails because the value is "US$100.00", but I'd like it to be "$100.00".
}
```

I had a look at `NumberFormatter` docs but couldn't see a property to disable this behaviour. I understand it's to avoid confusion with other $ currencies.

Do I have to write my own NumberFormatter subclass for this, or is there a simple way do have this behaviour?

Comment: I think Custom Formatter is required.

Answer (score 0):

This little hack should do the job

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.currencyCode = "USD"
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
formatter.currencySymbol = formatter.currencySymbol
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my tests. Can you elaborate on why you think this would work? It does work if I take a copy of the currency symbol _before_ setting the locale though. So that's a good workaround!